# iphone, coredata, nsfetchedresults controller, delete object , delete uitableviewcell not working

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am trying to delete `Core Data` object with nefetched results controller in `UITableView`, objects get deleted but cell is not removed and tablecelldeleteanimation is not wokring
working

```
objtableview.delegate = otherdelegateobject; 
objtableview.datasource = otherdatasourceobject;
```

in table view editing style datasource method , i am removing coredata object, so nsfetchedresults controller delegate method called...

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath { 
switch(type) { 
case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete: 
[self.tblRecentSearch reloadData];
```

(see full text)
its removing core data object, but called to tableview reload data not working
looks like may be thread related issue, may be i am trying to reload table from another thread..

Answer (score 0):

The `reloadData` method will only work after you have *saved* the change. The whole purpose of the delegate callback is to modify the rows manually, so the change can be animated.

```
case:NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
    [self.tblRecentSearch deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath];
                                withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```